# Anchors to pages not working?

Tags: html, href

Im trying to learn html and i ran into trouble,

**This is the homepage:**

```
<head>
    <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Welcome to ....</h1>

    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Homepage</h2>
    <p>Homepage content...</p>

</body>
```

**The second page:**

```
<head>
    <title>Page 2</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Welcome to ...</h1>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li>Page 2</li>
        <li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Page 2</h2>
    <p>Page 2 content...</p>

</body>
```

**The Third page:**

```
<head>
    <title>Page 3</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Welcome to ...</h1>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
        <li>Page 3</li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Page 3</h2>
    <p>Page 3 content...</p>

</body>
```

I saved them in one folder on my desktop but for some reason whenever I click the 2nd or 3rd page links in chrome it just tells me that the webpage is not found. Please help.

Comment: All pages are well called? `page2.html` should be exactly as this, case sensitive.

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me. Are you sure all your `.html` files are in the same directory? Are you sure the extension has been set to `.html`? Sometimes, text editors append `.txt` automatically; giving you `index.html.txt`.

Comment: While saving the file you should select "all files" , by default it takes as "text files". ie page2.html.txt

Comment: Be sure that all your pages are in the same directory and the names are exactly the same (case sensitive). Also, if you are on Linux or Mac, try ./page1.html, ./index.html. Even if what you did should work just fine, we never know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone,

I had spaces in the file names, it got fixed when i removed them. The names must be exactly the same as the .html href links in the files.